# VB.net httpclient receives Header OK 200, but content is empty

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I use MS Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10 and tried following httpclient by VB.net in order to get html of, for example, yahoo.com. I could get Header OK status 200 while its contents consists of several funny letters and finally resulsted in empty when converting to string.
Would you please advise how to receive contents by means of httpclient?
I tried variety sets of header which are not a cause of the problem.  I assume the cause exists in how to convert the contents or I may need to access again the site after receiving a header in order to receive the content???.

```
Dim url As String = "https://yahoo.com"
    Dim httpclienthandler0 = New HttpClientHandler()
    httpclienthandler0.UseCookies = True        
    httpclienthandler0.SslProtocols = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls13
    httpclienthandler0.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = AddressOf OnRemoteCertificateValidationCallback
    Dim httpclient0 As New HttpClient(httpclienthandler0)
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")        
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3")
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    httpclient0.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36")


    httpclient0.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)

    Try            
        Dim res As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpclient0.GetAsync(New Uri(url))

        res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

        Dim responseBody As String = Await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

        Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")

        Dim html As String = String.Empty

        Using stream = Await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
            Using reader = DirectCast(New IO.StreamReader(stream, enc, True), IO.TextReader)
                html = Await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As HttpRequestException
        Dim ex1 As Exception = ex
        While (ex1 IsNot Nothing)
            Console.WriteLine("Ex Message: {0} ", ex1.Message)
            ex1 = ex1.InnerException
        End While
    Catch ex As TaskCanceledException 
        Dim ex2 As Exception = ex          
        Console.WriteLine(vbCr + "Timeout!)
        Console.WriteLine("Ex MEssage: {0} ", ex2.Message)
    End Try
```

Following codes derived from above are specific code that gets empty contents.

```
Dim responseBody As String = Await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

and I tried next code instead of responseBody.

```
Using stream = Await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
            Using reader = DirectCast(New IO.StreamReader(stream, enc, True), IO.TextReader)
                html = Await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
            End Using
End Using
```

However both code resulted in empty.

Thank you indeed for your time to read and answer.

Comment: Set `Option Strict ON` right away. Don't look back. -- Remove TLS13, you cannot handle it. -- Remove `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests`, -- Remove `br` from `gzip, deflate, br` if you're using .Net Framework, add `httpclienthandler0.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate`. Add `DecompressionMethods.Brotli` if you're on .Net 5+ -- You just need `dim html = Await httpclient0.GetStringAsync(New Uri(url))`, you can remove the rest. -- That's not the way to use HttpClient, BTW.

Comment: It works perfectly. I removed and add code that you advised. I close this question now thanks to you.